# Validating left justified string in Java

Tags: java, string

I am getting a String value and need to validate if it is left justified or not.

In **org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils**, there are methods to make a value as left or right justified, but i need to check a value if it is left justified or not.

I can write the logic, but looking for any already built in functionality for the same,if exists.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: What do you mean? The string should not start with white space?

Comment: @jlordo - i can write the logic of validating it, but due to time constraint if any already built-in functionality is there..that will be helpful

Comment: @Henry - search on google first what is meant by left justified value

Comment: @Anand - he wants to know what >>>YOU<<< mean by left justified.  Specifically, in this context.  Googling for a general definition won't answer that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you understand "left justified" to mean "no writespace to the left", then the solution is obvious.  Test the first character of the String to see if it is a whitespace character.  It can be coded in 15 seconds and that should be the end of it.

---

The problem with "solutions" like `StringUtils.isBlank()` are manifold:

- You've added an extra JAR dependency for a 2 line method.
- You've spent 5 minutes finding the method, checking its spelling, check the javadoc to refresh your memory on what "blank" means, checking what it does will `null`s, coding the import.
- You've made work for the next guy who reads your code who potentially has to find / read the javadoc, etc.

For something like this, it is simpler just to code the test inline to do exactly what you need.  And it the code is easier to read ... unless your code is *full* of tests for blank / justified / whatever.

(And besides, this is not exactly what justified means.  Justification *normally* refers to text that spans multiple lines ...)

Comment: @Anand - This is a less than 1 minute programming task for anyone with decent Java skills.  You probably spent > 10 minutes asking the question and commenting.   And to date, 40 minutes waiting for an answer.  Go figure ...

Comment: That's what my problem was.You didn't get my question. Let me explain with an example..suppose we need to put some null checks..what we do is like if (value == null)..bu we have StringUtils.isBlank(value) which does the same job even though value == null is 15 sec. job..

Answer (score 0):

presuming the padding is always spaces, you could try

```
boolean leftJustified = (myString != null) && !myString.startsWith(" ");
```

good luck!

Comment: I disagree with the first part.  Testing if the String is not-null is not part of the problem.  A null String in this context should be viewed as "bad data", and an NPE is the best thing that can happen.